# how to add zeros after decimal in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add zeroes after the number .
for eg  a=  6895
then a= 6895.00

datatype of a is number(12);

I am using the below code .

```
select to_char(6895,'0000.00')  from dual .
```

I m getting the desired result from above code but
'6895' can be any number.so due to that i need to add '0' in above code manually.
for eg.

```
select to_char(68955698,'00000000.00')  from dual .
```

Can any one suggest me the better method .

Comment: Maybe you can change the datatype of a to number(12,2) or number(14,2)

Comment: Maybe nvl(a, 0) || '.00'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [number format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) are the place to start when converting numbers to characters. `0` prepends `0`s, which means you'd have to get rid of them somehow. However, `9` means:

> Returns value with the specified number of digits with a leading space if positive or with a leading minus if negative. Leading zeros are blank, except for a zero value, which returns a zero for the integer part of the fixed-point number.

So, the following gets you almost there, save for the leading space:

```
SQL> select to_char(987, '9999.00') from dual;

TO_CHAR(
--------
  987.00
```

You then need to use a [format model modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216), `FM`, which is described thusly:

> FM Fill mode. Oracle uses trailing blank characters and leading zeroes
>   to fill format elements to a constant width. The width is equal to the
>   display width of the largest element for the relevant format model
>
> ...
>
> The FM modifier suppresses the above padding in the return value of
>   the TO_CHAR function.

This gives you a format model of `fm9999.00`, which'll work:

```
SQL> select to_char(987, 'fm9999.00') from dual;

TO_CHAR(
--------
987.00
```

If you want a lot of digits before the decimal then simply add a lot of `9`s.

Answer (score 1):

> datatype of a is number(12);

Then use 12 9s in the format model. And, keep the decimal to just 2. So, since the column datatype is `NUMBER(12)`, you cannot have any number more than the given size.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 12 num FROM dual union ALL
  3  SELECT 234 num FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 9999 num FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 123456789 num FROM dual)
  6  SELECT to_char(num,'999999999999D99') FROM DATA
  7  /

TO_CHAR(NUM,'999
----------------
           12.00
          234.00
         9999.00
    123456789.00

SQL>
```

**Update** Regarding leading spaces

```
SQL>  select ltrim(to_char(549,'999999999999.00')) from dual;

LTRIM(TO_CHAR(54
----------------
549.00

SQL>
```

Comment: adding 12 - 9s will shift me data . ie.  if  to_char(549,'999999999999.00') will show my data as=_________549.00        
"____" are the spaces .

Answer (score 0):

With using `CASE` and `SUBSTR` it is very simple.

```
CASE WHEN SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME,1,1) = '.' THEN '0'||COLUMN_NAME ELSE COLUMN_NAME END
```