# Convert oracle data with two zeros after decimal

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a requirement in Oracle.

```
Sample Data
-----------
345
34
23423
```

I want the output to like this

```
Expected output
---------------
345.00
34.00
23423.00
```

The query can be either generic or specific to Oracle.

The to_char function in oracle can be used, but the length of the data is more than 25 so the to_char will fail there.

Comment: I tried using to_char(345,999.99), cast etc.. But the problem is the length of the data is varying.

Comment: Why you do not use the DecimalFormat class in your javacode?

Comment: That is the problem, I am Sqooping the data and dumping into HDFS. So the only option available is to do with sql query. I don't want to run an extra MapReduce on top of it to convert the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add zeros after decimal in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583179/how-to-add-zeros-after-decimal-in-oracle)

Comment: it is not a duplicate of the above mentioned question. I have data that is of length more than 20 in column. I need to append a two zero after decimal. the to_char function the possibile 999 that you give have a limit. Can you try that ?

Comment: `to_char()` does not have a limit of 25 characters: `to_char(some_column, '99999999999999999999999999999999999999999.00')` will work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will be dirty, but yet it works for you.

```
to_char(number_value,'FM'||LPAD(9,38,9)||'.90')
```

Using the MAX 38 digit value as the format model.

```
with my_data(number_value) as
  (
    select 999999999999 from dual
    union 
    select 9 from dual
    union
    select .009 from dual
    union
    select .9 from dual
    union
    select 999 from dual
  )
  select to_char(number_value,'FM'||LPAD(9,38,9)||'.90') from my_data;
```

Comment: Great man.. I was looking for a solution like this. Thank you so much....

Comment: to_char(number_value,'FM'||LPAD(9,38,9)||'.90') worked great for me. Can please explain what this means 'FM'||LPAD(9,38,9)||'.90'

Comment: For example `LPAD(A,5,A) = AAAAA` (5 times).. Am just forming the length format model(99999999.. blahblah), using this.

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like

(NOTE: Adapt number of "9" to have correct output with longest number you can have)

```
select a, to_char( a, '999999999990.00' ) from T;

|      A | TO_CHAR(A,'999999999990.00') |
|--------|------------------------------|
|    0.1 |                         0.10 |
|   0.02 |                         0.02 |
|      2 |                         2.00 |
|    2.2 |                         2.20 |
|   2.22 |                         2.22 |
|  10.22 |                        10.22 |
| 101.22 |                       101.22 |
```

SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a168/6

EDIT: That is why I have put NOTE at the begin, depending on your number. 
For your case you can put

```
select to_char( 1234567891011121314, '9999999999999999990.00' ) from dual;
```

For numeric(32,2) that can be:

```
create table T ( a numeric(32,2) );
insert into T values( 123456789012345678901234567890.12 ); 

| TO_CHAR(A,'999999999999999999999999999990.00') |
|------------------------------------------------|
|              123456789012345678901234567890.12 |
```

Comment: **select to_char( 1234567891011121314, '999999999990.00' ) from dual;** Can you try now ? I can't predict length of value. The size given in schema is Number(32,2) meaning a value with size 32 can be stored.

Comment: select to_char(98754666666666666231654654654564564545645645645646456665456456456456456445, '9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.99') AS AMOUNT from dual; This will not work in this case.

Comment: This already go over Oracle's numeric type precision limit.  You won't be able to have your data stored in table with the value you mentioned.   And, this solution is effectively just the same as the later-answered-accepted solution.  The only difference is simply that answer is using `lpad` to construct that long line of `9`s

Comment: Added example for numeric(32,2)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT
   CAST(YOUR_COL as decimal(38,2)) as OUTPUT
FOM xyz
```

or google!

Comment: I tried **SELECT CAST(456 as decimal(38,2)) as OUTPUT FROM DUAL;** The result is 456. What I want is 456.00.

Comment: Interesting, it was correct on my ORA-System. This must be some db configuration then. Thanks for the feedback.